# Passport.js facebook authentication doesn't execute

Tags: node.js, authentication, passport.js, passport-facebook

I've had authentication with passport-facebook working fine for months. As of two or three days ago, it hangs on the first request at /auth/facebook/connect and doesn't go on to the callback. It doesn't log any errors, break the application, or go on to the specified failureRedirect, either, it just hangs for ~59 seconds and then the request times out.

The weirdest part: it always works as expected in the debugger, just not when it's running on its own (either in the foreground or in the background using forever, which is my normal setup). All my npm packages are the same versions I've been using all along. Local auth is still working fine.

The only thing I have changed on this timeframe was adding Ruxit's monitoring agent to my staging server, but I can't imagine why this would be the issue. It does go back to working fine if I spin up a new instance, with or without the monitor- but if I do have the monitor installed, authentication stops working again at some point within a 24-hour period.

This is just super weird. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm voting to close this as off-topic because it's not possible to be solved right here. I suggest you search for help through the official ruxit support channels.

Comment: It turned out to be a Ruxit bug, they fixed it. :) Thanks!